# I write a bash file using tab-completion by complete command, but in zsh it didn't work

Tags: bash, zsh, tab-completion, bash-completion

source code:

```
#!/bin/bash

complete -W 'word1 word2 word3 aa bb' ./test.bash
echo "the param is: $1"
```

When I run ./test.bash , turns out the file list of current dir.

complete command doesn't work in zsh??

Answer (score 1):

Bash and Zsh are two different shells though they share quite a lot of common syntax. But you simply cannot expect all Bash things to work in Zsh.

Comment: Google: zsh auto complete

Comment: @fujian26 `zsh` has completion facilities, but they are very different from `bash`'s. See `man zshcompwid`, `man zshcompsys`, and `man zshcompctl`.